# Building Library Basics for C++ in Code::Blocks Using Open-Source Code

Tags: c++, static-libraries, codeblocks

I've looked and not found quite what I need in terms of building a library in Code::Blocks (which is probably because I'm very new to programming, so please bear with me).

I've downloaded a library to use for my program (I want to integrate with Twitter), and am trying to follow the [instructions for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/wiki/WikiHowToUseTwitcurlLibrary) provided with the code.

When I open the solution .sln file, I see all the source and header files I'm assuming should go in my library. I then create a new project, select "Static Library", and create the file. The the new project appears in my workspace with the file `main.c` which has some dummy functions.

This is where I'm extremely confused. The point of the library is to make it to where I shouldn't have to include all the separate source and header files, right? Do I have to copy all the contents of the header files into `main.c`? This seems wrong, but I'm not sure what to do.

I've checked a bunch of beginners tutorials, but none of them address what to do with building new libraries from open-source code. They only show how to link the library to the application.

Comment: Use Visual Studio instead of Code:: Blocks if you want to use the .sln file. Alternatively, you could use gcc and a text editor as stated in the instructions.

Comment: I'm really unsure what you want to do here. Do you know what the purpose of a .lib file is? Do you know what a library header is for ? .sln files are so called solution files for visual studio they probably will not work in Code::Blocks

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late for an answer, but in Code::Blocks you can just click on Projects -> Import -> MS Visual Studio Solution while inside the project.